# What are the names of gates of Paradise?

Tags: jannah

I have heard the there are more than one gate to paradise or if I am not mistaken, there are 7.

If so, then what are their names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are in fact [eight doors](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/42), four of the names are agreed up by the scholars, the names of the others are disagreed up by the those who explain the Ahadeeth.  I will mention six of the names:

1. [الصلاة Salat](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/226)
2. [الجهاد Jihad](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/226)
3. [الصدقة Assadaqah](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/226)
4. [الريان Ar-Rayyan](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/9/226)
5. الأيمن Al Ayman
6. باب الكاظمين الغيظ

My Over All source is: [islamweb.net](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/17317)

Answer (score 6):

### Heaven has Eight Gates

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Paradise has eight gates, ...... [[Narrated Sahl bin Sa`d](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/67)]

### Names

- **Baab As-Salaat** for those who were sincerely offered prayers (salaat)
- **Baab Al-Jihad** for those who have died  jihad
- **Baab As-Sadaqah** for those who give charity (sadaqah)
- **Baab Ar-Rayyaan** for those who observed fasting
- **Baab Al-Hajj** for those who observe the Hajj pilgrimage
- **Baab Al-Kaazimeen Al-Ghaiz Wal Aafina Anin Naas**  for those who control their anger and forgive others.
- **Baab Al-Iman**  for the entry of such people having sincere faith and trust in Allah
- **Baab Al-Dhikr** for those who constantly remembered Allah (dhikr)

<sup>collected from different sources [ [1](http://www.mahmoodiyah.org.za/faq494.htm) [2](http://www.albalagh.net/qa/names_gates_Jannah.shtml) [3](http://www.everymuslim.co.za/index.php/articles-menu/miscellaneous-menu/940-names-of-the-doors-of-jannah) ]</sup>