# Symbols of mercy in Islam?

Tags: symbolism

What are the possible symbols of mercy and/or compassion in Islam? As always answers with supporting references are appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? See if this helps, I just read today that there is a specific [gate in heaven](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/16707/9123) for those who show mercy.

Comment: Please elaborate: Do you mean practical symbols or textual ...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the word 'grace' mentioned in the koran? If so what is the meaning of it?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30014/is-the-word-grace-mentioned-in-the-koran-if-so-what-is-the-meaning-of-it)

Answer (score -1):

The Symbols in Islam are Arabic symbols where the words were derived. 
The word Mercy in Arabic "Rahmah" came from the "Rahim" which means the womb of the mother. It feeds, supplies, protects, builds, and delivers the baby. If the baby needs any nutrition that is lacking in the mother. Then the baby's needs take precedence on the expense of the mother.

Allah said in Hadieth Qudsi (Sacred statements, 3rd source of Islam). I am the most Merciful "Al-Rahman" and I derived for the kin relationship "Rahim" a name from my name. "Whoever connects the relation of Kin, I will connect with him, and whoever cuts the relation of kin, I will cut him off"

The Messenger PBUH was walking with the companions and he saw a mother crying when she finally found her lost baby. She keeps kissing and crying then the messenger said "would any one of you imagine that this mother might throw her baby in fire?". 
The companions said no o messenger of Allah. 
Allah is more merciful on His servant than this woman on her baby. 
Google the following in Arabic من هذه المرأة بولدها
I hope that I answered your question.

Comment: "If the baby needs any nutrition that is lacking in the mother. Then the baby's needs take precedence on the expense of the mother." I'm skeptical about this, any proof?