# Is dua not an option but an obligation?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, dua, hell, obligation

Do you MUST make dua? Is it a voluntary or do we MUST?

Will one go to hell if the Muslim does not make dua?

If so, what type of duas?

Types of Dua

Dua al mas’ala (ask) e.g. Grant me …
Dua al Ibaadah (worship) e.g. La Ilaaha Illallah

Is one of the types of the duas written above superior or more favored to Allah?
 Or does Allah love both of the duas the same?

In the hadith that Allah gets angry when one does not ask of him.
 What will happen once Allah gets angry? 
Does that mean you go to hell for not making dua?

Comment: Why don't you get started with [Du'as from Qur'an](http://www.duas.org/25duanew.htm). Maybe you'll get a better picture. *Dua al Ibaadah (worship) e.g. La Ilaaha Illallah* which you're referring to could simply be called as *remembrance of Allah*, AFAIK. And, there is a [gate in heaven](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/16707/9123) for those who remember Allah much.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is based on my knowledge and research.**

**May Allah Grant me strength to guide you well, right and forgive me for my mistake**

Its good that you make Dua (Allah very much like this act), Well, who don't ask Dua (in sense of arrogance(Ghuroor & Takabbur) ) will consider himself in hell. here some ayat and some more details. [link1](http://www.ramadan.com.au/benefits-and-power-of-dua) [Link2](http://www.islamreligion.com/articles/4005/dua-supplication-part-1/)

I am giving you small example, I hope you will understand the importance of Dua, Eg: you are ill, and went to a doctor, Dr suggest you some medicine, you bought that but you are not taking those medicine and hoping that i will get fine (which is not possible). same, you are not making Dua and hoping for good doesnot make sense.

> As there are multiple time mentioned in Quran & Hadith about dua. and
>   on daily basis(Tahujjud Time, usually after Isha prayer till morning
>   prayer adaan time) Allah says, is there any one who has something to
>   ask(Dua) and I(Allah) will complete (accept) his/her Dua.

So, Effort and Dua are must for each other. Do effort and ask Dua.

Here are some dua's, read its translation[image]